# Disposing a timer while the callback accesses it

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

**Edit**
This is a simplified example. I have code similar to this in a windows service.

I have the following code. How do I make absolutely sure I don't get a `NullReferenceException` when i'm stopping the timer. I want to change the timer inside the callback because the work i'm doing may take different amounts of time.

```
static Timer timer = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 5000, -1);
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
    timer.Dispose();
    timer = null;
}

static void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    //do work
    Console.WriteLine("Doing work");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    //do I need a lock here? or an if (timer != null)
    timer.Change(5000, -1);
}
```

Do I need a lock like this? Is this the best way?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 5000, -1);
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
    lock (timerlock)
    {
        timer.Dispose();
        timer = null;
    }
}

static void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    //do work
    Console.WriteLine("Doing work");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    lock (timerlock)
    {
        if (timer != null) 
            timer.Change(5000, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: When and where exactly do you get an NRE?

Comment: if the main thread just got past this line `timer = null` while the callback wants to do this: `timer.Change(5000, -1);`

Comment: @CodeCaster He could get a NRE while calling `timer.Change(5000, -1);` if it so happened that he pressed Return at just the right (or wrong!) moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the simplest and safest way.

You're accessing shared state - the `timer` field. Any multi-threaded access to shared state must be synchronized, which is what the `lock` is for. It's really rather straight-forward :)

However, do note that you're not *waiting* for the timer callback to be done - if your application exits, the callback will be aborted midway. This may cause you trouble, of course.

The easiest way to solve this would be to use some signalling primitive to make sure the main threads waits for the callback to complete.

Comment: Thanks. This was just a simplified example. This is part of a windows service. I tried to take the essential parts out and put them in a question.

Comment: "However, do note that you're not waiting for the timer callback to be done" : Yes, I'm aware of that.